# MySQL connection with advanced attributes such as program_name

Tags: java, mysql, scala, jdbc, mysql-workbench

When I create a new connection to MySQL data base through mysql jdbc driver I see next advanced attributes in my MySQL Workbench:

[image]

We can see next attributes:

- _runtime_version
- _client_version
- _client_name
- _client_license
- _runtime_vendor

How we manage these attributes?

Connection that was created by MySQL Workbench has other attributes:
[image]

How can I set the 'program_name' attribute while connection creation or my own attributes?

Comment: you could just simply create your own program to connect to the MySQL database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found in this article [Connection attributes in MySQL 5.6](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/03/26/connection-attributes-in-mysql-5-6/)

There is example of url with additional attributes:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/login?connectionAttributes=program_name:Login Server,other_name:other
```

[image]